# Get the selected date from python/nicegui

Tags: python, nicegui

I have two functions for getting date from user, which are:

```py
def date_selector():
    with ui.input('Date') as date:
        with date.add_slot('append'):
            ui.icon('edit_calendar').on('click', lambda: menu.open()).classes('cursor-pointer')
    with ui.menu() as menu:
        ui.date().bind_value(date)
    s_date = date.value
    print(s_date)
    return s_date
def tab_date():
    ui.label(date_selector())
    return
```

But it is not assign value to s_date. How can I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a `ui.date` element and immediately read its value. But the user had no chance to set any value, yet.

Instead you should react on the `on_change` event, e.g. like this:

```py
def handle_date(event):
    ui.label(event.value)
    menu.close()


with ui.input('Date', on_change=handle_date) as date:
    with date.add_slot('append'):
        ui.icon('edit_calendar').on('click', lambda: menu.open()).classes('cursor-pointer')
with ui.menu() as menu:
    ui.date().bind_value(date)
```

Comment: Answer worked. But I delete the menu.close(), because I use second part as a function and it does not see "menu". Also if I understand correctly, for all evens I should write the event handler.